# An extremely peculiar compiler issue

Tags: c, compiler-construction, embedded, microcontroller

I've written code for PIC16F1947 in C. I am using the following:

- MPLAB IDE 8.73
- HI-TECH C Compiler 9.81

A part of the code deals with data coming from PC. The specific packet I'm sending from PC is 325 bytes. This packet looks as follows:

```
data:  0, 64, 1, 0, 255, 255, 255, ... (all 255) ..., 255,   1
index: 0   1  2  3    4    5    6                     323  324
```

The contents of the packet are shown as 8 bit decimal value (8 bit unsigned integer). The micro stores it in an array of `unsigned char`:

```
unsigned char _command_mgr_buff[330];
```

`unsigned char` is the 8 bit unsigned integer for PIC16F.

The last byte of the packet, ie index 324, is the checksum of the packet. It is the summation of index 1 through 323, including 1 and 323. The PC code (in C#) that calculates this checksum is as follows:

```
allCertPages[324] = 0;
for (int i = 1; i <= 323; i++)
{
    allCertPages[324] += allCertPages[i];
}
```

`allCertPages` is a `byte[]`.

The micro must verify that the checksum is indeed the value passed from PC. Here is the verification code that I've written for PIC16F, including some debug information:

```
param0 = _command_mgr_buff[324]; // param0 is unsigned int, 16 bit
param1 = _command_mgr_buff[324]; // param1 is unsigned int, 16 bit

// Checksum verification
for (var = 1; var <= 323; var++) // var is unsigned int, 16 bit
{
    _command_mgr_buff[324] -= _command_mgr_buff[var];
    param1 -= _command_mgr_buff[var];
}

if (!_command_mgr_buff[324])
{
    send_status(CS_BAD_PARAM);
}
```

The idea is to subtract all values within the range [1, 323] from the checksum. If the final value is 0, then checksum is correct. Otherwise, if `_command_mgr_buff[324]` is found non-zero after subtraction, then the checksum is incorrect.

After executing the code in debug mode (and also in release mode), I'm getting non-zero value in `_command_mgr_buff[324]` (so `send_status(CS_BAD_PARAM);` gets executed and the PC thinks something is wrong), but zero in the lower byte of `param1`!

How is that possible?!

In case you're interested, here is the assembly generated for the non-zero checking:

```
  8780                           ;mgr_command.c: 1230: if (!_command_mgr_buff[324])
  8781  0E89  30EA                  movlw   low(8870+0144h)
  8782  0E8A  00D3                  movwf   (??_command_mgr_run+0)^080h+0
  8783  0E8B  3023                  movlw   high(8870+0144h)
  8784  0E8C  00D4                  movwf   (??_command_mgr_run+0)^080h+0+1
  8785  0E8D  0853                  movf    0+(??_command_mgr_run+0)^080h+0,w
  8786  0E8E  0086                  movwf   fsr1l
  8787  0E8F  0854                  movf    1+(??_command_mgr_run+0)^080h+0,w
  8788  0E90  0087                  movwf   fsr1h
  8789                           
  8790  0E91  0881                  movf    indf1,f
  8791  0E92  1D03                  skipz
  8792  0E93  2E95                  goto    u10101
  8793  0E94  2E96                  goto    u10100
  8794  0E95                     u10101:
  8795  0E95  2E9B                  goto    l55070
  8796  0E96                     u10100:
  8797                              line    1232
  8798                              
  8799  0E96                     l55068:    
  8800                           ;mgr_command.c: 1231: {
  8801                           ;mgr_command.c: 1232: send_status(0x11);
  8802  0E96  3011                  movlw   (011h)
  8803  0E97  31B6  2693  3188      fcall   _send_status
  8804                              line    1233
  8805                           ;mgr_command.c: 1233: }
  8806  0E9A  2FE3                  goto    l45048
  8807                              line    1234
```

Here is a screenshot taken during debugging. Please check the Watch window in the right and the tooltip for 324-th element.

- `param0` should be 1
- `param1 & 0xFF` should be 0
- **`_command_mgr_buff[324]` should be 0 (tooltip shows 0x0F??!!)**

[image: PIC16F Debug]

Comment: What else is your firmware doing? You should reduce your code to only the checksum calculation, with data values from a static const array, if you want to check whether it is the checksum calculation which causes the problem (unlikely). Otherwise it could be anything if it's a complete system: PC sending another string that partially overwrites the first, other buffer overruns, ASM ISRs where not all required registers are preserved, etc.

Comment: 324 is a bad index for _command_mgr_buff[324]. BTW sizeof can help you to avoid all these literal numbers. IMHO a program should contain only three numbers: 0, 1 and sizeof.

Comment: @wildplasser: the communication protocol between PC and the micro is strictly defined and they won't be changed. If any change in protocol requires, then a new command will be created. also, the array _command_mgr_buff is of size 330. sizeof won't work here.

Comment: I stand corrected. BTW why are you summing into `allCertPages[324]` ; you should easily sum into an unsigned temp variable and assign the final value to `allCertPages[324]`. ("downcasting" between unsigned types is guaranteed to be a modulo truncation).WRT sizeof: I still there are too many magic numbers in the code fragment. (maybe you did that that to make the explanation easier?)

Comment: @wildplasser: regarding summing into allCertPages[324], i don't see any difference between your method and the way i did it. regarding magic numbers, may be i could define a WRITE_CERT_CHECKSUM to 324 and use that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your code is as you say, the main problem here is your test itself:

```
if (!_command_mgr_buff[324])
{
    send_status(CS_BAD_PARAM);
}
```

You're sending the signal if the result is what you want (namely zero)...

This is one of the reasons why I don't like boolean testing of non-boolean values.  Boolean variables often have names that cue you into reading the condition they capture correctly, like `if (isLoaded)` or `if (!anyErrors)`...and that doesn't hold for numerics.  So it's easier to make sure you've got the semantics you want to just write it out:

```
if (_command_mgr_buff[324] != 0) 
{
    send_status(CS_BAD_PARAM);
}
```

As for why your debugger is giving you the 0x0F...can't help you there...my point just being that you're in the zero branch. You might try a clean build and see if it still says that.  (The program's debug symbols could be out of date or something?)

Comment: To the OP: May I suggest adopting MISRA-C? Rule 13.2, "Test of value against zero should be made explicit, unless the operand is effectively Boolean". This bug wouldn't have passed a MISRA-C checker. Nor would the addressing of an array out-of-bounds bug pass one. An array declared as `Type arr[N];` cannot be accessed with `arr[N]`... C uses zero-indexed arrays.

Comment: @HostileFork: what do you mean by 'zero branch'?

Comment: @Donotalo I didn't mean anything special...just the branch where the value is zero (the `else` branch would be for non-zero values tested).  MISRA-C is new to me too, interesting...I'll have to look into the MISRA-C++